# Symfony 2 - missing mandatory parameters exception on twig extends

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm currently getting a very wired twig exception:

If I use the twig `{% extends 'some:template' %}`, I get the following twig exception:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The "_projectView" route has some missing mandatory parameters ("id").") in "xy:Project:view.html.twig".
```

But if I remove `{% extends 'some:template' %}`, the template is displayed correctly - this for my part rules out any problems with routing or the controller, it has to be a problem with the template but I can't figure it out. No variables are used in the parent templates.

Comment: Why would you want to extend ''? That function expects a string. If you don't want to extend another template, don't add the extend tag. Or is this just for demonstrating purposes?

Comment: Yeah bad choice ... In my actual implementation there is of course a valid template path, I just left it in the example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside the template you're trying to extend you're trying to generate a url from a route '_projectView'  but you don't provide all necessary parameters.

Either add a default id to your route ...

```
route_name:
    pattern: /whatever/{id}
    defaults: { id: 1 }
```

... or do something like this in your template:

```
{{ path('route', { 'id' : entity.id|default('1') }) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just to confirm: If this would be the case, every page that extends the given template should show the same exception? The funny thing is I __only__ get the error on the 'view' template that the rout points to. The page that links to the 'view' page which contains a path just as you mentioned works just fine ...

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, to display correctly, each twig needs to have all the variables it needs defined.  They are either in the URL or passed into the render function.  If any of these variables are missing, then Symfony will throw this error.

Given what you've said it seems to me that the twig you are extending has a variable in it that it wants.  In all other places you have extended this twig, you have provided this variable already either in the URL or in one of the parent twigs and so it has not complained.  In this case you try to use it and that variable is missing.  So it complains.

Check to make sure your route passes in the right variable or that your controller passes the right variable into the render function.